# Show ! sign after # in url when i route in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs,i try a demo test for routing ,below is my codes

app.js

```
 var app=angular.module("tutorialApp",["ngRoute","tutorialCtrlModule"]);

 app.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
        .when("/",{
            templateUrl:"views/tutorial.html",
    controller:"TutorialCtrl"
})
.when("/tutorialsecond",{
            templateUrl:"views/tutorialSecond.html",
    controller:"TutorialCtrl2"
});
});
```

tutorialCtrl.js

```
     angular.module("tutorialCtrlModule",[])

    .controller("TutorialCtrl",["$scope",function($scope){
            $scope.name = 'dipti';
            $scope.bindvalue = 2;
            $scope.timesTwo = function(){
                $scope.bindvalue *=2;
            }                            
    }])

    .controller("TutorialCtrl2",["$scope",function($scope){
            $scope.name = 'Dipti';
    }]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="tutorialApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial App</title>
    <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/tutorialCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my routing pages

tutorial.html

```
    <u><h3>Route Page</h3></u>
        <u>Expression</u>
        <br>
    {{ name }}
    <br>
    <u>Data Binding</u>
    <br>
    <label>Name</label>
    <br>
    <input ng-model="name">
    <br>
    <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 1 }}</p>

    <br>   
    <a href="#/tutorialsecond">Tutorial Second Page</a>
```

When i load my project the default page tutorial.html will show,but ! sign will come in my url like http://localhost/Angular_demo/#!/
When i click on link in tutorial.html page for routing it not working and this url will show     http://localhost/Angular_demo/#!/#%2Ftutorialsecond.How i will slove it.

Comment: change your anchors from `href="#/..."` to `href="#!/..."`

Comment: i changed it to href="#!" but same url will show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your hash prefix correctly

```
angular.module('myApp').config([  
    '$locationProvider',
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // or whatever you want
    }
]);
```

Extra:

make sure html5mode is active

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and that your base is set

```
<base href"/"/>
```

Comment: I am use this  app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
            .when("/",{
                templateUrl:"views/tutorial.html",
        controller:"TutorialCtrl"
    })
    .when("/tutorialsecond",{
                templateUrl:"views/tutorialSecond.html",
        controller:"TutorialCtrl2"
    })
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

});  but it will url like  http://localhost/Angular_demo/#/!/